# How to change the default hyperlink on asp.net page c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a  webpage that is set to a default page that displays certain data when the user clicks on the Item number but depending on what the item is I want to display a different data from a different hyperlink.  I'm writing a function in Default.aspx.cs page under

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsCallback)

    {
        //if it's different item than go to this hyperlink instead
       // HyperLink1.NavigateUrl
    }
}
```

I don't know how to write the function to change the hyperlink.  Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a little confusing. You are saying the page "displays data when the user clicks", then you are saying you want to follow a link. Either way, I think you are lacking some very basic concepts of web applications. In order for someone to help you, you need be more specific, or this will become an open-ended question.

Comment: I meant that when the user clicks on the Item number than it shows the test data for that item but depending on the type of item the data changes so I don't want it to go the default hyperlink page but instead go to a second hyperlink that shows the correct data.  Example by default it goes to Hyperlink page A but I want to change it to B.  I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: Response.Redirect()?...

Comment: Why not just set the hyperlink to the correct URL to start with?

Comment: @Snixtor Because the information changes depending on the item otherwise that would be a simple change.

Comment: But if you're generating the URL, you'll know the details of the item it relates to. I feel like there's something missing from your description.

Comment: @Snixtor   I have two different pages because the data is in two different db tables and it's not related. So for example you have a student and a teacher they both have the paramter ID and initially they see the same default page but when they click on their ID they will get different information displayed by 2 different aspx pages (1 page for students and 1 for teachers)  I want the pages to be redirected to the appropriate page depending on their ID number. Unless there is an easier way to do this, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: On the default page, you know what their ID is. Perform a database lookup to determine whether that ID corresponds to a student or teacher, and set the `NavigateUrl` accordingly.